# Incompatible types error on arraylists, can not assign

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am a new programmer. On my journey to make a navigation drawer with expandable list view, I got stuck on some incompatible types errors. I can't seem to understand any defects. It should work, but gives error.

> ```
> subCategoryName:
> java...com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory>>
> subcategory_name  (java...com.gts.plandigit.Util.Category>>)
> ```

on this code fragment-->

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mCategoryList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_sliderMenu);
mCategoryList.setAdapter(new expandableListViewAdapter(PostLoginActivity.this,category_name,subcategory_name, subCatCount));
```

> ```
> Incompatible types.
> Required:
> ArrayList
> <com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory>
> Found:
> ArrayList
> <com.gts.plandigit.Util.Category>
> ```

on this line-->

```
tempList =  subcategory_name.get(groupPosition);
```

And finally as I was adding the subcategories to related categories this error

> ```
> add
> (java.util.ArrayList<com.gts.plandigit.Util.Category>)
> in ArrayList cannot be applied
> to
> (java.util.ArrayList<com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory>)
> ```

every use of this line -->

```
subcategory_name.add(subCategoryMatches);
```

I can not see what is wrong. It should work as adding the subcategory objects inside the related category elements. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** Here are my arraylists

```
private ArrayList<Category> category_name = new ArrayList<Category>();
private ArrayList <ArrayList<Category>> subcategory_name = new ArrayList 
<ArrayList<Category>>();
private ArrayList<Integer> subCatCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Can you put the code where you defined the arraylists?

Comment: @uneq95 Sorry about that, I have just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all of your error log, we can see summarize that the error is the same, i.e:

```
Incompatible types.
Required:
ArrayList
<com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory>
Found:
ArrayList
<com.gts.plandigit.Util.Category>
```

That's means that you just using the wrong class involuntarily. You're naming your variable with `subcategory_name` but it is a `Category` object not `SubCategory` object. So, you need a strict naming convention for your variables.

Comment: Changed one of my arraylist as you said from this

private ArrayList<Category> category_name = new ArrayList<Category>(); 
to this
      private ArrayList <SubCategory> subcategory_name = new ArrayList <SubCategory>();

An interesting error still is there..
subCategoryName:
java...com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory>>
subcategory_name  (java...com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory>) and also see;
add
(com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory)
in ArrayList cannot be applied
to
(java.util.ArrayList<com.gts.plandigit.Util.SubCategory>)